# RegEx Quickie Special Selection

Tags: regex, string

Alright, I'm no pro at RegExpression so can someone give me the reg expression that would select the `display()` and `first_name` in the following haystack string?:

```
$Question -> display();
$Person -> first_name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `->\s+(.*);$`

```
>>> re.search(r'->\s+(.*);$', '$Question -> display();').group(1)
'display()'
>>> re.search(r'->\s+(.*);$', '$Person -> first_name;').group(1)
'first_name'
```

Comment: what does the \s mean in regex?

Comment: @Dick It's a character class that matches any whitespace, including a normal space, tab, etc. If you just want to allow for a single space, replace the `\s+` with a space. But `\s+` makes the regex more robust to slight format changes.